# How to copy files to folder with execlp?

Tags: c, execl

I need to copy a file (the name of the file is entered via the keyboard) inside a folder (called backup) using execpl

```
printf("File name to copy? ");
scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);

char *args[] = { "cp", str,"/backup" };

p = fork();  
// Fork validations + Dad wait for child

execlp(args[0],args[0], args[1], args[2], NULL);
exit(1);
```

Comment: Are you aware that array indexing in C is zero-based?

Comment: true true ... i haven´t noticed!

Comment: @Mark Please don't add [Resolved] to your title. You show your problem is solved by accepting an answer (which you did).

Comment: @George Stocker Ok thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `execlp` is the command to run, and the arguments that follow are the command line arguments to the command.  The first of these arguments is always the program being run.

So you need to duplicate the first element in the array:

```
execlp(args[0], args[0], args[1], args[2], NULL);
```

Comment: 100% Functional! Thanks a lot